# What experts suggest to embrace change in an organization?

Tags: project-management-style

What are the best lines quoted by project management experts for adopting change in a company.

Comment: Project managers aren't there to create change; they are there to ensure execution.

Comment: "best lines" is subjective; makes it difficult to select an authoritative answer.

Answer (score 1):

Change within the context of **project management** is anything that transforms or impacts **projects, tasks, processes, structures**. **Change management** refers to the **tools and processes** you use to manage **change within a project** and a project team. I'm not sure your question is in the context of project management, however, I find it very interesting. This is an article with twenty transformational quotes on **Change Management**:

https://www.toprightpartners.com/insights/20-transformational-quotes-on-change-management/